# Combining 2 Strings variable into 1 and make them a date format flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have 2 dropdown buttons that return the String variable from the String of the list after the user chooses one of the list.

This is a variable I created

```
  String? selectedMonthEnd;
  String? selectedYearEnd;
```

This is the code of 2 dropdowns

```
                 Row(
                  children: [
                    //End Month
                    Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10, left: 26),
                      width: 170,
                      padding:
                          EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12, vertical: 4),
                      child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
                        child: DropdownButton<String>(
                          hint: Text(
                            'Choose Month',
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 17,
                                color: Colors.black,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                          ),
                          value: selectedMonthEnd,
                          isExpanded: true,
                          iconSize: 30,
                          icon: Icon(
                            Icons.arrow_drop_down,
                            color: Colors.black,
                          ),
                          items: month.map(buildMenuItem).toList(),
                          onChanged: (value) => setState(() {
                            this.selectedMonthEnd = value;
                          }),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    // End Year
                    Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 12, left: 10),
                      width: 120,
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric( horizontal: 12,vertical: 4,),
                      child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
                        child: DropdownButton<String>(
                          hint: Text(
                            'Choose Year',
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 17,
                                color: Colors.black,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                          ),
                          value: selectedYearEnd,
                          isExpanded: true,
                          iconSize: 30,
                          icon: Icon(
                            Icons.arrow_drop_down,
                            color: Colors.black,
                          ),
                          items: year.map(buildMenuItem).toList(),
                          onChanged: (value) => setState(() {
                            this.selectedYearEnd = value;
                          }),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
```

This is what I'm trying to do, combining them and turning them into date time format then saving them into a Firestore database.

This is the code to save them in firestore database

```
try {
      String date1 = selectedMonthStart! + selectedYearStart.toString();//combining 2 strings
      DateFormat datestart = DateFormat.yMMMM(date1);//make them a date
      print(datestart);
      String date2 = selectedMonthEnd! + selectedYearEnd.toString();//combining
      DateFormat dateend = DateFormat.yMMMM(date2); //make them a date
      print(dateend);  

      print(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.uid);
      await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection("education")
          .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
          .set({
        "uid": FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.uid,
        "College": collegeAheadController.text,
        "imageCollege": imageuniversitycollege,
        "Major": SelectedMajor,
        "Degree": SelectedDegree,
        "StartDate": datestart,
        "EndDate": dateend,
      }).then((value) => print("Data changed successfully"));
    } on FirebaseException catch (e) {
      Utils.showSnackBar(e.message);
    }
```

[image]

I want to make the 2 strings from the dropdowns into date format, then add them into firestore database

Answer (score 1):

The parameter takes in a String but you added `[date2]` which is equivalent to List of String:

Try this instead:

```dart
  DateFormat dateend = DateFormat.yMMMM(date2);
```

Comment: Yes thankyou @Georgina, i updated the code but get the error instead

Comment: @JessenJie Please show error. Show what is in `date2`  and `date1`

Comment: i screenshot it in the question @Georgina

Comment: @JessenJie I think you should post the new error as a different question. Meanwhile tick my answer as correct